# Drupal7 Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 24 bytes)

Tags: drupal-7

I have this code that connect an external mysql database and retun columns values

```
   for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($Columns); $i++) {
        //$Columns contains columns names in a current datatable $dt  

        $result3 = Database::getConnection()->query("SELECT ".$Columns[$i]." From ".$dt." ");  
        $field_values = array();
        $index = 0;

                while ($row = $result3->fetchAssoc()) {
                             $field_values [$index] = $row[$Columns[$i]];
                             //drupal_set_message($field_values[$index]);
                             $index++;
         }
```

The code work fine for any data table except one that contains thousend of columns and evry column contains many values..In the case of this data table drupal display a fatal error related to the allowed memory:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 24 bytes) in C:\xampp\htdocs\.....
```

I want to escape this error by trying to get only a few columns so I did the next:

```
while ($row = $result3->fetchAssoc() && $index<=3) {
             }
```

But drupal still displaying this error any idea how to avoid such an error?

Answer (score 0):

It might be a good idea to use [Batch API](https://drupal.org/node/180528) for this. But you will have to find the smallest chunk that could be processed without overloading your server. Since this is highly dependent on the data you have, and the data you "don't" have too ( future data ). You may want to split it up int o very very small chunks.

maybe you can,

```
<?php
for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($Columns); $i++) {
  // Send to batch processing.
}
```

If that doesn't work, then you will have to,

```
<?php
for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($Columns); $i++) {
  // Do a count query get max
  // split into smaller batches using paging in SQL ( hint: LIMIT 0, 10).
  foreach($pages as $page) {
    // Send to batch processing.
  }
}
```

Please refer to the Batch API documentation i had linked to, it explains how you could define batch process and pass your parameters to them.